# Ukulele prodigy said Do-Re-Mi-Fa-Sol took him three months to learn - what does this mean?

Tags: theory, ukulele, solfege

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGkpCjpsDIY&feature=youtu.be#t=0m15s), at around 18 seconds, ukulele guitar prodigy Feng E said his father taught him how to play ukulele, and he learned Do-Re-Mi-Fa-Sol in three months, which, according to him, might be a new world record.

Surely, this kid might be a new world record. But I am somehow baffled by specifically this statement about Do-Re-Mi-Fa-Sol - what does it mean?

Do-Re-Mi-Fa-Sol are the first five notes of a major scale (movable do), or of the C major scale (fixed do) - learning to sing them is, I guess, easy. So, what he could have meant when saying he learnt Do-Re-Mi-Fa-Sol?

Comment: That may be his way of saying he learned to sing solfege in 3 months...

Comment: But singing a major scale is easy, even people with no formal music training can do it ... so what's the point...

Comment: I don’t quite get it, maybe he did an entire solfege course...or maybe his dad is easily impressed.

Comment: He's definitely an exceptional talent - but saying he is proud to do solfege (in three months), it is like... dont know... Neil Armstrong saying he is proud he can jump up a single staircase with his bare feet, or Steven Spielberg announcing he is able to hold a camera, or Linus Torvalds that he can type a word on a keyboard, or... anyway

Comment: Seems like total bs to me.

Comment: Yeah, I doubt there is a deeper meaning here. I guess another possibility, allowing for the difference in languages, could be that he learned the "Do-Re-Mi" song from *The Sound of Music.*

Comment: I think it's sol.  And three months is a long time to learn those 5 notes.

Comment: There's no denying he plays uke well. But where's solfege?

Comment: Maybe he meant he learnt where all the five notes are on the neck or maybe he learnt all the positions on the neck for all the five major chords. But it is all guessing; after all you have to take into consideration that a child prodigy is still a child and you where reading a translation from a language whose meaning nuances are not always easy to translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In China, the most commonly used method for referring to musical notes is to use the solfege syllables, ("do re mi" in Western music); however, they do understand and use Western notation. So I think he means sight-reading, hence the Guinness reference.